# How can I show another value instead of NULL in a sum?

Tags: mysql

How can I show "1" instead of NULL?

Here my tables:

```
|policies|
    |id| |policy|
      1    abc
      2    def

|insurances|
     |id|  |policy_id| |money|
       1         1       1000
       2         1       2000  
       3         2       3000
       4         2       4000 
       5         1       1000
```

Here the query:

```
 select sum(money) as cash from insurances i
 INNER JOIN policies p ON p.id = i.policy_id
 WHERE i.policy_id = 3
 Group by i.policy_id
```

In this case when policy_id= 3 it shows NULL:

```
 |cash|
   NULL
```

I want to show:

```
 |cash|
   1
```

Also I tried, but didn't worked:

```
 select sum(money)+1 as cash from insurances i
 INNER JOIN policies p ON p.id = i.policy_id
 WHERE i.policy_id = 3
 Group by i.policy_id;
```

[Here is the link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79979/10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(money), 1) as Cash
FROM (
  SELECT policy_id, money
  FROM
    insurances i INNER JOIN policies p
    ON p.id = i.policy_id
  WHERE
    i.policy_id = 1
) s
```

**edit** or you could try with this little trick:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(cash), 1) FROM (
  SELECT sum(money) AS cash
  FROM   insurances i
         INNER JOIN policies p ON p.id = i.policy_id
  WHERE i.policy_id = 3
  GROUP BY i.policy_id
) s
```

Comment: I tried your code and i got 4000 instead of 0.......http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79979/30

Comment: @CarlitosMorales please see it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79979/38 i had to remove group by

Comment: ok fthiella your code seems to be working but do you have another way? Because not working in production when it has 5000 rows

Comment: @CarlitosMorales please see my updated answer... hope it works

Comment: I' mean another way without using COALESCE using if NULL

Comment: @CarlitosMorales my first query could be slower but my second one should be as fast as your original one so if it works without coalesce it should work fine....

Comment: Well in my example id=3 is not showing anything , i read about COALESCE and it replaces NULL for values , but i'm having a column cash that is not showing anything also it's not showing NULL like blank or doesn't exist that's why i want something like IF or ELSE to replace

Comment: @CarlitosMorales yes, the trick is not to use COALESCE but to use an aggregated function with no GROUP BY clause (an your original query as a subquery): this way it will always return one row